# Instagram new API, get items by tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, pagination, instagram, instagram-api

Last month Instagram API was updated and I can't understand how work with it.

For example I want to get images via tag `nexus5x`.

I do request to `https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/nexus5x?access_token=access_token`

and response is

> 200
>   '{"meta":{"code":200},"data":{"media_count":5066,"name":"nexus5x"}}'

Can you explain me what to do next?

I also tried get recent items

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/nexus5x/media/recent?access_token=access_token`

but get this response

> 200 '{"pagination":{"deprecation_warning":"next_max_id and min_id are
>   deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id
>   instead"},"meta":{"code":200},"data":[]}'

P.S. App in sandbox.

Comment: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/#get_tags_media_recent, you may need to pass some parameters

Comment: that is only the notice,, can you try to generate new access token and see if that works,, I got the 'nexus5x' list ok! ofcorse with my secret token..

Answer (score 1):

You are in Sandbox mode, so it will return only media from your sandbox authorized user, here is information about this:

> As another example, let's consider an endpoint that returns a list of
>   media: /tags/{tag-name}/media/recent. The response returned by this
>   endpoint will contain only media with the given tag, as expected. But
>   instead of returning media from any public Instagram user, it will
>   return only media that belongs to your sandbox users, restricted to
>   the last 20 for each user.

So if u add a post in instagram with the hashtag then it will show up in api response, this is restriction in sandbox mode

Here is the link to more details about Sandbox mode: https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/