# Instagram API: I want to get recent images based on tag, but I only recieve my own

Tags: api, tags, instagram

I want to use `Instagram API` to get the latest images based on a specific tag.

When I use:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

I only recieve the images that my user has created with that tag. I want to get all tagged images, not just my own. Is it supposed to do that?

When I try:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Then it works and I get statistics from not just my own images.
Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 2):

You are in Sandbox mode, so it will return only media from your sandbox authorized user, here is information about this:

> As another example, let's consider an endpoint that returns a list of
>   media: /tags/{tag-name}/media/recent. The response returned by this
>   endpoint will contain only media with the given tag, as expected. But
>   instead of returning media from any public Instagram user, it will
>   return only media that belongs to your sandbox users, restricted to
>   the last 20 for each user.

Here is the link to more details about Sandbox mode: https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/

Once your app is approved, you will see all media.

Comment: Is there any app that does that for me?

Comment: @mwm to get just hashtag results, you can use instagram.com and search for it

Comment: really? this is an API related question. I know I can use the web site to search. I want to do it programatically. (also scraping is probably illegal)

Comment: then use APIs and do it (APIs are listed in question), get your app reviewed and approved from Instagram and u can do your own, I did it with https://www.picodash.com . what exactly is your questions? u want to do a app that gets hashtag data or need an app that has this functionality?

Comment: why do I need an app reviewed/aproved (with obligatory screencast?!) for a simple backend request to an already public content /tag/{tag}/recent/media. I just need a valid access_token. terrible API

Comment: people had started abusing the APIs to auto like, auto follow and gaming the system, so Instagram now only gives API access to legit people who are building an app/platform for brands/people, they usually dont approve one off apps which will be used within a company or for personal use, if you want to do a one-off app, they recommend you to use existing app that already does what you are looking for.

Comment: I see what you mean but this is a public resource already. a read only pub. resource. I don't want to build an App. It isn't even "screencastable" for their approval. It's full backend. it's ridiculous. even if I wanted to make this "app" for many clients to use, it wouldn't pass because there is nothing visible to show. also, if they want me to use apps that already do that, they should have an "app-store" so one could browse for such "apps" (clients).

Comment: if its an app for many clients (platform), you can get approval if it meets the usecase, just show marketing landing page explaining what the app is, does not have to be UI for app, there will be some UI that clients will come to register or login or request service right? show that in screencast, what does the app do?

Comment: yes, instagram is pretty stupid in this. you cannot even submit an app that is fully backend one. the whole concept of "instagram apps" and what they imagine it to be is pretty ridiculous