# How can I get the public data of Instagram filtered by tags

Tags: python, instagram

I am using Instagram API, I would like to access to all the media data using a filter (let's say in my case I am filtering #HappyNewYear status ).

I used this code, but it seems that I am getting the ones from timeline ? How can I make sure I am getting all the public data ?

```
api = InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token, client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET)

tag_recent_media, next = api.tag_recent_media(tag_name='#HappyNewYear')
photos = []

for tag_media in tag_recent_media:
    print(tag_media.get_standard_resolution_url())
    print(tag_media.like_count)
    print(tag_media.caption.text)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34397561/i-want-to-get-latest-images-based-on-tag-but-only-recieve-my-own-instagram-ap