# Instagram API returning only logged in user data rather than public

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

I am following https://github.com/sachin-handiekar/jInstagram/wiki/jInstagram-Usage

The below code only returns data posted by me while I need public data.

```
String tagName = "snow";
TagMediaFeed mediaFeed = instagram.getRecentMediaTags(tagName);

List<MediaFeedData> mediaFeeds = mediaFeed.getData();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue, [New Instagram API - How do you request tagged media?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34190332/new-instagram-api-how-do-you-request-tagged-media/34190613#34190613)

[That is the expected sandbox behavior.](https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/#api-behavior)