# Can't receive images by hashtag

Tags: instagram-api

I'm trying to get all images with a specific tag by Instagram API.
First I send this request:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/tag?access_token=XXXX
```

and get response:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "code": 200
  },
  "data": {
    "media_count": 8215885,
    "name": "tag"
  }
}
```

Then I try to start receive an images by next request:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/tag/media/recent?access_token=XXXX
```

Result is:

```
{
  "pagination": {
    "deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead"
  },
  "meta": {
    "code": 200
  },
  "data": []
}
```

Why `data` is empty?
I tried to send this request by adding `count` parameter, result was the same. I think maybe 
min_tag_id or max_tag_id is required, but I don't know where I can get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trouble was in sandbox mode. **Without LIVE mode app can receive only media that belongs to it's sandbox users.** Answered here: [New Instagram API - How do you request tagged media?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34190332/new-instagram-api-how-do-you-request-tagged-media#34190613)